# Check if Set of functions is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the functions $f_1 = \sin,  f_2= \cos, f_3: x \rightarrow 1$ and the subspace which gets created by the span of These functions. Now, if I have to show that the vector $(f_1, f_2, f_3) $ is a Basis of my subspace, what do I do? I cannot quite imagine what a subspace created by functions even looks like. Any hints?

Comment: Well, it "looks like" itself: the set of functions $\{a\sin x+b\cos x+c\,:\,a,b,c\in\Bbb R^3\}$

Comment: To test independence you can look at the Wronskian determinant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+c_31=0$

Differentiating both sides $\text{w.r.t}$ $x$ we get $c_1\cos x-c_2\sin x=0\rightarrow (1)$

Again differentiating both sides $\text{w.r.t}$ $x$ we get $c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x=0\rightarrow (2)$

Eliminating we $c_2(\sin^2 x+\cos ^2 x)=1\implies c_2=0$

Again putting $c_2=0$ in $(1)\implies c_1\cos x=0$. Putting $x=0$ we get $c_1=0$

Hence $c_3=0$.

Hence $\text{span($x_1,x_2,x_3$)}=\{c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+c_31:c_,c_2,c_3\in F\}$
 has dimension $3$.

Comment: This makes sense, what I dont understand however is: Why are you allowed to differentiate to solve this equation?

Comment: Because it is a polynomial identity

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that

$$\exists a,b,c \in\mathbb R : \forall x\in \mathbb R  $$

$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)+c.1=0$$

then

$$x=0 \implies b+c=0$$

$$x=\pi \implies b=c=0$$

$$x=\frac{\pi}{2} \implies a=0$$

You conclude.